# iTunes Connect add in app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm following along with this https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial  tutorial for setting up In App Purchases in iOS Apps,  and having problems creating the In App purchase for the first time in iTunes Connect. The option to create a non consumable iap is not available.  I think I'm missing something.

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjfil.jpg for a screenshot.

IAP is enabled in my app, I've uploaded my app to iTunes connect. Not sure what's going on. Any advice?  I'm on XCode 8, Swift 3.

Comment: Have you completed the tax and banking forms in iTunes connect?  Can you list apps at a price tier other than "free"?

Comment: Thanks that worked.